# mongodb multiple find and replace old value with new value in any field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to find and replace (update) the values of any field in all my documents with the following pattern:

```
{[<oldValue1>:<newValue1>,<oldValue2>:<newValue2>,<oldValue3>:<newValue3>]}
```

i have hundreds of this kind of old/new values, and they are spread over multiple fields, I want to look for them wherever they are in the fields, and update them with their corresponding new value.

how can I achieve this?

Comment: It looks like you want to update values in an array is that correct? What you've written is not a valid JSON object, so I am not sure what we are looking at right now. Also I am not sure this is a good question. I think mods will flag it. It should be more of a learining experience for everyone reading this rather than: "Solve this code for me".

Comment: Do you want to update values to new values or do you want them to be updated in the pattern that you have specified.

Comment: @ShantanuMadane they should be updated according to the pattern. For example, the old value `12345` will be replaced by new value `67890` wherever in the fields.

Comment: Basically you want to do find and replace type of thing

Comment: @ShantanuMadane yes, but i don't know the field names, they could be anything. I want to find the values wherever they are, and replace with new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this solution.

var cursor = db.test.find();
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
          var x = cursor.next();
          var arr=[{"oldvalue":"newvalue"},{"oldvalue":"newvalue"}];
          for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
          var keys=Object.keys(arr[i]);    
          print("Before: "+keys[0]);
          x[keys[0]] = x[keys[0]].replace(x[keys[0],arr[i][keys[0]]);
          print("After: "+keys[0]);
          db.test.update({_id : x._id}, x);
        }
    }
```